# Splitting in Dart

Tags: dart

How to Spilt this paymentUrl.

```
const _paymentUrl =
        'bitcoin:3QF3iP4PZPw51qB5w6Jpo8j7P4AXyS83ra?amount=0.00107000';
```

TO Get

```
{Address: "3QF3iP4PZPw51qB5w6Jpo8j7P4AXyS83ra", Amount: "0.00107000"}
```

Comment: please clarify, are you trying to insert the values from the url into the a Map with those keys and values?

Comment: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/RegExp-class.html

Comment: Yes! thats what am trying  to do. Above is a scanned payment link.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a URI, and is named like a URI, so try using the `Uri` class:

```dart
const _paymentUrl =
    'bitcoin:3QF3iP4PZPw51qB5w6Jpo8j7P4AXyS83ra?amount=0.00107000';

var bcUri = Uri.parse(_paymentUrl);
var address = bcUri.path;
var amount = bcUri.queryParameters["amount"];
var map = {"Address": address, "Amount": amount};
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems the `?` is always there, so you can split it based on it like this:

```dart
  const _paymentUrl = 'bitcoin:3QF3iP4PZPw51qB5w6Jpo8j7P4AXyS83ra?amount=0.00107000';
  
  List<String> splitPayment = _paymentUrl.split('?');
  String bitcoin  = splitPayment[0];
  String amount = splitPayment[1];
```